# how to loop through table in laravel calculate sum of a column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How do i calculate the totals of all values of a `column amount` after fetching it in laravel controller. table `collections` has only `amount and id` column and i want to determine the totals.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` from eloquent:

```
$amount = Collections::sum('amount');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$total = 0;
$amounts = Collections::all()->pluck('amount');
foreach($amounts as $amount){
  $total += $amount;
}
```